# nopCommerce4.10 show warning while get from tfs and in the result the build was failed

Tags: git, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

The setup:

- nopCommerce4.10 version are used.
- Push to git repository and build successfully.
- Clone git repository in another laptop machine.
- when trying to build the solution it arise the following waring
- Using Visual studio 2017

The error message:

```
Severity Code Descriptin Project File  Line  Suppression State
Warning  NETSDK1071 A PackageReference to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' 
specified a Version of `2.1.2`. 

Specifying the version of this package is not recommended. 
For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs 
Nop.Core C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets 153
```

Answer (score 0):

See if [dotnet/sdk issue 2602](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2602) applies:

> You should be able to set the `AllowExplicitVersion` metadata on the `PackageReference` to `true` in order to suppress this warning.
>
> This is supposed to happen [automatically](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/62632dd6369517e9a7a01dd68cbbdc126ca43a5f/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets#L115-L118) if you have `DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences` set to true. Are you adding `PackageReference` after the evaluation of the SDK targets?
>
> Aha, yes. That was it.
> We generate our `PackageReference` items during a target.
> **Adding `AllowExplicitVersion=true` to the metadata works**.

As in [PR 3482](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/pull/3482/files):

```
<AllowExplicitVersion>true</AllowExplicitVersion>
```